Very old horror short story about a dead man waking up
A dead man wakes up because his cemetery is being plowed up so they can build something there (apartments, houses, a parking lot?). I think the man kills the person running the bulldozer or backhoe? He then starts walking around. He goes to the library for information about something and people remark about how pale he is; they assume he's one of the people who've recently returned from the Moon or Mars. I think he kills people here, or is maybe horrified, and runs away. He goes to a water or waste treatment plant with a tour, talks to some of the men in the tour group, and kills people here, or tries to and ends up dying (again).
I swear it isn't Ray Bradbury, as we read this AFTER we covered Bradbury (for class), but it's very much in the same vein, which was why we were covering it, obviously. Does anyone know the name of the story?

You're 100% sure it's not Ray Bradbury? Have you read his "Pillar of Fire"? You can read it here: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/64673

Hi Oliver. As user14111 suggests this is Bradbury's story Pillar of Fire. It has all the plot points you mention. @user14111 you should post that as an answer.

"Pillar of Fire", a 1948 novelette by Ray Bradbury, available at Project Gutenberg. You may have read it in one of these compilations. It was also the answer to the old questions A short story of an animated dead man in a world with no fear of death and What Ray Bradbury story contains a line about autumn burning the land?, and the literature.SE question Help finding a book/short story about a man who comes back from the dead and finds himself in a world that's forgotten fear.
A dead man wakes up because his cemetery is being plowed up . . .

He looked at the graveyard. It was cold and empty. All of the stones had been ripped up and piled like so many flat bricks, one atop another, in the far corner by the wrought iron fence. This had been going on for two endless weeks. In his deep secret coffin he had heard the heartless, wild stirring as the men jabbed the earth with cold spades and tore out the coffins and carried away the withered ancient bodies to be burned. Twisting with fear in his coffin, he had waited for them to come to him.
Today they had arrived at his coffin. But—late. They had dug down to within an inch of the lid. Five o'clock bell, time for quitting. Home to supper. The workers had gone off. Tomorrow they would finish the job, they said, shrugging into their coats.
Silence had come to the emptied tombyard.
Carefully, quietly, with a soft rattling of sod, the coffin lid had lifted.
William Lantry stood trembling now, in the last cemetery on Earth.

. . . so they can build something there (apartments, houses, a parking lot?).
I don't think the story mentions plans for use of the cemetary grounds after the inhabitants have been dug up and burned. Mainly they want to be rid of the cemetary and corpses:

He trembled. How very close it had been. Day after day they had hauled out the other dead ones, burned them like so much kindling. An edict had been broadcast around the world. He had heard the digging men talk as they worked!
"I guess it's a good idea, this cleaning up the graveyards," said one of the men.
"Guess so," said another. "Grisly custom. Can you imagine? Being buried, I mean! Unhealthy! All them germs!"

I think the man kills the person running the bulldozer or backhoe?
He kills the first man he meets, but it's not one of the diggers:

Footsteps. Lantry hastened to the edge of the cemetery. The diggers, coming back to finish up their work? No. Just someone, a man, walking by.
As the man came abreast the cemetery gate, Lantry stepped swiftly out. "Good evening," said the man, smiling.
Lantry struck the man in the face. The man fell. Lantry bent quietly down and hit the man a killing blow across the neck with the side of his hand.
Dragging the body back into shadow, he stripped it, changed clothes with it. It wouldn't do for a fellow to go wandering about this future world with ancient clothing on. He found a small pocket knife in the man's coat; not much of a knife, but enough if you knew how to handle it properly. He knew how.

He goes to the library for information about something . . .

He looked at the librarian. May I help you, may I help you. What a world of helpful people! "I'd like to 'have' Edgar Allan Poe." His verb was carefully chosen. He didn't say 'read'. He was too afraid that books were passé, that printing itself was a lost art. Maybe all 'books' today were in the form of fully delineated three-dimensional motion pictures. How in hell could you make a motion picture out of Socrates, Schopenhauer, Nietzsche and Freud?

. . . and people remark about how pale he is; they assume he's one of the people who've recently returned from the Moon or Mars.

And another thing, this paleness of his. He looked at his hands and realized with growing terror that a pale man also was non-existent in this world. They would suspect his paleness. That was why the first attendant had asked, "Are you one of those men newly returned from Mars?" Here, now, this new Attendant was clean and bright as a copper penny, his cheeks red with health and energy. Lantry hid his pale hands in his pockets. But he was fully aware of the searching the Attendant did on his face.

He goes to a water or waste treatment plant with a tour, talks to some of the men in the tour group, and kills people here . . .
He goes to an Incinerater and blows it up after killing the attendant with his knife:

William Lantry was five miles away at the time of the explosion. He saw the town ignited by the great spreading cremation of it. And he shook his head and laughed a little bit and clapped his hands smartly together.
Relatively simple. You walked around killing people who didn't believe in murder, had only heard of it indirectly as some dim gone custom of the old barbarian races. You walked into the control room of the Incinerator and said, "How do you work this Incinerator?" and the control man told you, because everybody told the truth in this world of the future, nobody lied, there was no reason to lie, there was no danger to lie against. There was only one criminal in the world, and nobody knew HE existed yet.
Oh, it was an incredibly beautiful set-up. The Control Man had told him just how the Incinerator worked, what pressure gauges controlled the flood of fire gasses going up the flue, what levers were adjusted or readjusted. He and Lantry had had quite a talk. It was an easy free world. People trusted people. A moment later Lantry had shoved a knife in the Control Man also and set the pressure gauges for an overload to occur half an hour later, and walked out of the Incinerator halls, whistling.

. . . and ends up dying (again).
In the end he is caught and incinerated:

All of these things am I. And now these last things will be burned. While I lived they still lived. While I moved and hated and existed, they still existed. I am all that remembers them. I am all of them that still goes on, and will not go on after tonight. Tonight, all of us, Poe and Bierce and Hamlet's father, we burn together. They will make a big heap of us and burn us like a bonfire, like things of Guy Fawkes' day, gasoline, torch-light, cries and all!

